# Property does not exist on type T

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a function generic. But i can't figure out why it says `[E] Property 'displayName' does not exist on type 'T[{ [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends Base ? k : never; }[keyof T]]'`.

```js
interface Base {
  id: string;
  displayName: string;
}

interface Station extends Base {
  district: Base;
  city: Base;
}

type Item<T> = { [ k in keyof T ]: T[k] extends Base ? k : never }[keyof T] | 'self';

type Result = { displayName: string };

const f = <T extends Base>(items: Item<T>[], obj: T): Result[] => {
  return items
    .map(item => {
      if (item === 'self') {
        return { displayName: obj.displayName };
      }
      return {
        displayName: obj[item].displayName, // displayName does not exist
      };
    });
};

const s: Station = {
  id: '1234',
  displayName: 'Station 1',
  district: { displayName: 'Test', id: '1' },
  city: { displayName: 'Testcity', id: '1' },
};

const r = f(['city', 'self'], s); // expected: [ { displayName: 'TestCity' }, { displayName: 'Station 1' } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `T` in function `f` refers to `Base`. Therefore `obj` is of type `Base`, and you cannot use any keys to index it other than `id` or `displayName`.

It seems like what you actually need is for `obj` to be a type which describes `Station`, rather than `Base`:

```
interface Base {
  id: string;
  displayName: string;
}

type ExtendedBase<K extends string> = [K] extends keyof [Base] ? never : {
    [key in K]: Base
} & Base

type Result = { displayName: string };

const f = <T extends string>(items: (T | 'self')[], obj: ExtendedBase<T>): Result[] => {
  return items
    .map(item => {
      if (item === 'self') {
        return { displayName: obj.displayName };
      }
      return {
        displayName: obj[item].displayName, //ok
      };
    });
};

const s = {
  id: '1234',
  displayName: 'Station 1',
  district: { displayName: 'Test', id: '1' },
  city: { displayName: 'Testcity', id: '1' },
};

const r = f(['city', 'self'], s); // Result[]
```

I have omitted the `Station` type simply because it isn't doing any work in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a solution with explanation in comments

```js
interface Base {
  id: string;
  displayName: string;
}

/**
 * Treat it as a simple callback for Array.prototype.map
 */
type MapPredicate<
  Key,
  Obj extends Base,
  /**
   * Represents first argument of applyBase function
   */
  Source extends Record<string, Base>
  > =
  /**
   * If Key is "self"
   */
  Key extends 'self'
  /**
   * Return obj.displayName
   */
  ? { displayName: Obj['displayName'] }
  /**
   * If Key extends keys of first argument of applyBase
   */
  : Key extends keyof Source
  ? Source[Key] extends Base
  /**
   * return obj[item].displayName (see js implementation)
   */
  ? { displayName: Source[Key]['displayName'] }
  : never
  : never


/**
 * Map through a tuple and apply MapPredicate to each element,
 * just like it is done in runtime representation
 */
type Mapped<
  Arr extends Array<any>,
  Obj extends Base,
  Source extends Record<string, Base>
  > = {
    [Key in keyof Arr]: MapPredicate<Arr[Key], Obj, Source>
  }

const builder = (obj: { displayName: string }) =>
  ({ displayName: obj.displayName })

/**
 * Simple validation of last argument (tuple of keys)
 * If elements extends either key of first argument of applyBase function or "self"
 *  - it is considered as allowed key, Otherwise - forbidden
 */
type Validation<Obj, Tuple extends unknown[]> = {
  [Key in keyof Tuple]: Tuple[Key] extends keyof Obj
  ? Tuple[Key]
  : Tuple[Key] extends 'self'
  ? Tuple[Key]
  : never
}

/**
 * Logic is simple, we need to infer literaly each provided argument
 */
function convert<
  BaseId extends string,
  BaseName extends string,
  BaseObj extends { id: BaseId, displayName: BaseName }
>(base: BaseObj): <
    NestedId extends string,
    NestedName extends string,
    Keys extends PropertyKey,
    Extension extends Record<Keys, { id: NestedId, displayName: NestedName }>,
    Items extends Array<Keys>
    >(obj: Extension, items: Validation<Extension, [...Items]>) => Mapped<[...Items], BaseObj, Extension>
function convert<
  BaseObj extends { id: string, displayName: string }
>(base: BaseObj) {
  return <
    Extension extends Record<PropertyKey, Base>,
    Items extends Array<PropertyKey>
  >(obj: Extension, items: Validation<Extension, [...Items]>) =>
    items
      .map(item =>
        item === 'self'
          ? builder(base)
          : builder(obj[item])
      )
}

const applyBase = convert(
  {
    id: '1234',
    displayName: 'Station 1',
  })

// const result: [{
//     displayName: "Testcity";
// }, {
//     displayName: "Station 1";
// }]
const result = applyBase(
  {
    district: { displayName: 'Test', id: '1' },
    city: { displayName: 'Testcity', id: '1' },
  }, ['city', 'self']);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mMMnzm)

As you might have noticed, I have splitted second argument into two parts to make it easier for TypeScript to infer them.

If you are interested in argument inference, you can check my [enter link description here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)